# AmpScript: Pulling in data from a data extension I'm not sending to

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have a data extension with the following fields:

Rebate_StartDate
Rebate_endDate
Rebate_amount
Rebate_Text

I want to list these attributes in an email as rows using Ampscript, but I can't seem to figure it out. I can't use the lookup function because the data extension I'm mailing to doesn't have a value I can lookup attributes off of.

What can I do to create this with Ampscript?
Basically I'm trying to pull in data from a data extension I'm not emailing to and don't have a matching characteristic to lookup off of

Comment: So how will you know which row to display in who’s email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest adding a new Number field to your data extension called `lookupKey` and set it's default value to `1`.

Export your data and import it back into your Data Extension, so all the new rows will have a default value of `1` in the `lookupKey` field.

Then your lookup could be something like this:

```ampscript
%%[

set @rebates = LookupOrderedRows("Rebates",0 ,"Rebate_StartDate asc", "lookupKey","1")
set @rowCount = RowCount(@rebates)

for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

  set @row = Row(@rebates,@i)
  set @Rebate_StartDate = field(@row, "Rebate_StartDate")
  set @Rebate_endDate = field(@row, "Rebate_endDate")
  set @Rebate_amount = field(@row, "Rebate_amount")
  set @Rebate_Text = field(@row, "Rebate_Text")

  if FormatDate(Now(),"YYYY/MM/dd") >= FormatDate(@Rebate_StartDate,"YYYY/MM/dd") 
     and FormatDate(Now(),"YYYY/MM/dd") <= FormatDate(@Rebate_endDate,"YYYY/MM/dd") then

      ]%%

      <br>Rebate_StartDate: %%=v(@Rebate_StartDate)=%%
      <br>Rebate_endDate: %%=v(@Rebate_endDate)=%%
      <br>Rebate_amount: %%=v(@Rebate_amount)=%%
      <br>Rebate_Text: %%=v(@Rebate_Text)=%%

      %%[
      else
      ]%%
        <br>No rebates available.
      %%[
      
  endif 

next @i 

]%%
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you for your help!